# Java Swing two Action Listeners on one JCheckBox

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

I have a `JCheckBox` with action listener implemented.

Here, when it's checked, something appears and when not checked, the appearance disappears.

To implement this, should I have two action listeners? How do I implement this?

Answer (score 3):

you can use `ActionListener` for this and when that action is fired you can check it's selected or not

```
final JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox("My checkbox"); 
checkBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        // check if checkBox is selected or not
        if(checkBox.isSelected()){
            // here you can fire an event in which your checkbox is mark as selected
            // and you can display the value you want to display
        } else{
            // checkBox is not selected so you can fire an event in which your checkbox is not selected
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a single `ActionListener` and you check the selected state of the `JCheckBox` through the use of it's [`isSelected`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#isSelected()) property.  A `ActionListener` can not distinguish states on it's own, it simply responds to a user input

See [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for more details.

Comment: Any example of this? I couldn't really find one on stackovervflow